# Word for "picking up something quickly/abruptly?"

Tags: single-word-requests

Say, you'd been expecting a call and the person suddenly calls. Is there a word that feels more 'rushed' than *pick up*? I checked [Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/pick+up) but none of the synonyms seems to fit the purpurse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snatch#Verb), *snatch* means “To grasp quickly. [eg] *He snatched up the phone*”.  Related senses of this verb include:
• To attempt to seize something suddenly; to catch
• To grasp and remove quickly
• To do something quickly due to limited time available
• To take or seize hastily, abruptly, or without permission or ceremony

Answer (score 2):

You can say that you **grabbed** the phone.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grab) has the following definitions for grab:

> - to quickly take and hold (someone or something) with your hand or arms
> - to take or get (something) in a quick and informal way
> - to take or seize by or as if by a sudden motion or grasp

Comment: Geez, I was updating my answer to include this also. But we can say that this generally means "taking quickly" instead of "picking up quickly".

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @jwpat7's "*snatch*", but with sillier overtones, there is ***snag***:

> ***[snag](http://dictionary.infoplease.com/snag)*** (Infoplease): *to grab; seize*; "to snag the last piece of pie"
>
> ***[snag](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/snag)*** (Cambridge ACD): *to obtain or catch something by acting quickly.* "I hoped to snag a good job."

And, of course, ever since season four of the Simpsons, we've that lovely little word: "***[YOINK](http://www.collegehumor.com/post/6990014/video-every-simpsons-yoink-supercut)***!"

[image: Bart Simpson *yoinking* Kent Brockman's danish]
<sub>(source: [nytmare.org](http://www.nytmare.org/misc/yoink-1F11.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can use the verb ***scoop*** *(up)*.

> to pick up (something or someone) in one quick, continuous motion [[MW]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scoop)

Example:

> He scooped the phone up. “Can't you people leave me alone for even a little while?” he shouted angrily.
>
> <sub>[Needful Things: The Last Castle Rock Story *By Stephen King*]</sub>

---

Note: I admit that this is less common than *to grab (the phone)* but more precise for the meaning.